# Reload filters based on previous checkboxes selected and affects that to data of a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

I am trying to change select boxes in order based on what is previously selected and affects that to next selections also to the table at the same time without reload the page.

This is the detail photo.

[image]

what is the easiest and right way to do that

- AJAX with GET ?
- should i learn AngularJS ?
- it can't be done with multi checkboxes and i must only have one value in parameter ?

how to logic it in php and AJAX in a right way ?

Comment: By 'the table', you means to update the database? or just for the html table elementt?

Comment: The html .table